# Calculate the Sum of same rows from different columns using Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

My actual data belong to Column G to N, where I've Name and quarter columns.
Column A contains 2 quarters and I want to calculate VAL1 and VAL2.

[image]

*Logic to create VAL1:*

- for 2021Q2, identify all the non-zero Names from Column M (2021Q2) then
  SUM values of (M,L,K) for the same Names.
- for 2021Q3, identify all the non-zero Names from Column N (2021Q3) then
  UM values of (N,M,L) for the same Names.

*Logic to create VAL2:*

- for 2021Q2, identify all the non-zero Names from Column M (2021Q2) then
  SUM values of (J,I,H) for the same Names.
- for 2021Q3, identify all the non-zero Names from Column N (2021Q3) then
  UM values of (K,J,I) for the same Names.

I've tried few approaches, like identify the location using ADDRESS(MATCH), getting ROW numbers, but didn't work properly. Can anyone please help with a formula to get the desired values?

Comment: It looks like you need [`Sumproduct`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e).  As we can't see the "few approaches" you tried in the post, are you able to provide that by updating your post?  One of those may have been useful and just need tweaking slightly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1] In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET($G$2,0,MATCH($A2,$H$1:$N$1,0),7)<>0)*OFFSET($G$2,0,MATCH($A2,$H$1:$N$1,0),7,-3))
```

2] In `C2`, formula copied down :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((OFFSET($G$2,0,MATCH($A2,$H$1:$N$1,0),7)<>0)*OFFSET($G$2,0,MATCH($A2,$H$1:$N$1,0)-3,7,-3))
```

[image]